# Mean Of Sum Of Upper Rows

Tags: sql

I expect someone could help me.

I made a table with some data, no need to know what in particual. I come from this `#TempTable1`:

```
WEEK_NUMBER         SUM         MEAN_OF_SUM
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                   10  
2                   20  
3                   30  
4                   60  
5                   30  
6                   60  
7                   0
```

My desired table `#TempTable1`:

```
WEEK_NUMBER         SUM         MEAN_OF_SUM
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                   10          10 --(10/1)
2                   20          15 --(30/2)
3                   30          20 --(60/3)
4                   60          30 --(120/4)
5                   30          30 --(150/5)
6                   60          35 --(210/6)
7                   0           30 --(210/7)
```

I tried with sums and expected the group by clause would work, but they do not. Does someone has an idea on how to solve this ?

Comment: Please explain the last value.

Comment: Can you please tell us expected result?

Comment: In french it would be so easy, harder for me to explain result in english. The result needed is, for each row (example row 4) the sum of the 4 data in wolumn "sum" divided by the weeknumber, here 4.
This has to be done for each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think are looking for a cumulative average:

```
select t.*, avg(sum*1.0) over (order by week_number)
from t;
```

This doesn't match the last value.  I'm guessing that is a typo.